# can't read '%' for request.getparameter()

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Hi i have a hyperlink from hyperlink i am calling a servlet and also sending a parameter with request but when '%' appended with text then shows null value.

**Code Of Jsp**

```
 <h1><a href="test11?val=100%">click</a></h1>
```

**Code of servlet**

```
 String s=request.getParameter("val");
   out.print("this is a text"+s);
```

for `<h1><a href="test11?val=100">click</a></h1>`
it works fine but when i add '%' it print null.

Comment: % is a special character in URLs. You have to encode it

Comment: Have you tried URL-encoding the `%`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the % from an `URL` you should use it's `URLEncoded` version which is **`%25`**. So you will end with `<h1><a href="test11?val=100%25">click</a></h1>`

`%` in an `URL` is not just a character, is the the main character for the [`percent-encoding`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) used in URLEncoding. Other special characters for URLs are `?`, `&` and `=`

Please try to always encode your URLs, in java please check this link:[Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding) in order to do so.

Comment: How to do it? Please specify.

Comment: replace '%' with '%25'

Comment: Your link shows how to do that in Java code, not in JSP.

Comment: just add %25 before the number it will treat it as %. So i would append %25 in my string.Thank you Garis

Comment: Note: if you post to do this using scriptlet, your answer would become awful.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using JSP then try with [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) to encode the URL.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:url value="/test11" var="url">
    <c:param name="val" value="100%" />
</c:url>

<a href="${url }">click</a>
```

Read more about [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/)

Comment: Note: we're at Java EE 7. Don't post links that belong to stone ages :).

Comment: Thank you @Braj That really helped me out. learn a new thing about JSTL